# Why SvelteKit basic example build output use the very modern import keyword?

Tags: rollupjs, sveltekit

In the [description of Svelte](https://svelte.dev/blog/whats-the-deal-with-sveltekit), Rich explained why it's important to use the `import` keyword for development, and I'm totally agree. He continues and says that in the production build it's using the traditional JavaScript packaging:

> That's not to say we're abandoning bundlers altogether. It's still essential to optimise your app for production, and SvelteKit uses Rollup to make your apps as fast and lean as they possibly can be (which includes things like extracting styles into static .css files).

But when I'm building the famous example from `npm init svelte@next` with adapter set to node, I see that the output JavaScript still use the `import` keyword in the pages JS, and also use `<link rel="modulepreload" ...>` which is super modern for browsers, as mentioned. For example, here is the output HTML of the built for production `index.html` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <title>Home</title>

        

        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/start-331a94d4.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/chunks/vendor-a4e104ac.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/pages/__layout.svelte-ad0878a7.js">
        <link rel="modulepreload" href="/_app/pages/index.svelte-49c07d7e.js">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_app/assets/start-61d1577b.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_app/assets/pages/__layout.svelte-a06e2686.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/_app/assets/pages/index.svelte-1ae03b51.css">

        <script type="module">
            import { start } from "/_app/start-331a94d4.js";
            start({
                target: document.querySelector("#svelte"),
                paths: {"base":"","assets":""},
                session: {},
                host: "127.0.0.1:3000",
                route: true,
                spa: false,
                trailing_slash: "never",
                hydrate: {
                    status: 200,
                    error: null,
                    nodes: [
                        import("/_app/pages/__layout.svelte-ad0878a7.js"),
                        import("/_app/pages/index.svelte-49c07d7e.js")
                    ],
                    page: {
                        host: "127.0.0.1:3000", // TODO this is redundant
                        path: "/",
                        query: new URLSearchParams(""),
                        params: {}
                    }
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="svelte">


<header class="svelte-1twf6mk"><div class="corner svelte-1twf6mk"><a href="https://kit.svelte.dev" class="svelte-1twf6mk"><img src="/_app/assets/svelte-logo-87df40b8.svg" alt="SvelteKit" class="svelte-1twf6mk"></a></div>

    <nav class="svelte-1twf6mk"><svg viewBox="0 0 2 3" aria-hidden="true" class="svelte-1twf6mk"><path d="M0,0 L1,2 C1.5,3 1.5,3 2,3 L2,0 Z" class="svelte-1twf6mk"></path></svg>
        <ul class="svelte-1twf6mk"><li class="svelte-1twf6mk active"><a sveltekit:prefetch href="/" class="svelte-1twf6mk">Home</a></li>
            <li class="svelte-1twf6mk"><a sveltekit:prefetch href="/about" class="svelte-1twf6mk">About</a></li>
            <li class="svelte-1twf6mk"><a sveltekit:prefetch href="/todos" class="svelte-1twf6mk">Todos</a></li></ul>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 2 3" aria-hidden="true" class="svelte-1twf6mk"><path d="M0,0 L0,3 C0.5,3 0.5,3 1,2 L2,0 Z" class="svelte-1twf6mk"></path></svg></nav>

    <div class="corner svelte-1twf6mk"></div>
</header>

<main class="svelte-1izrdc8">

<section class="svelte-mjk9ig"><h1 class="svelte-mjk9ig"><div class="welcome svelte-mjk9ig"><picture><source srcset="svelte-welcome.webp" type="image/webp">
                <img src="svelte-welcome.png" alt="Welcome" class="svelte-mjk9ig"></picture></div>

        to your new<br>SvelteKit app
    </h1>

    <h2>try editing <strong>src/routes/index.svelte</strong></h2>

    <div class="counter svelte-ltn89m"><button aria-label="Decrease the counter by one" class="svelte-ltn89m"><svg aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="svelte-ltn89m"><path d="M0,0.5 L1,0.5" class="svelte-ltn89m"></path></svg></button>

    <div class="counter-viewport svelte-ltn89m"><div class="counter-digits svelte-ltn89m" style="transform: translate(0, 0%)"><strong style="top: -100%" aria-hidden="true" class="svelte-ltn89m">1</strong>
            <strong class="svelte-ltn89m">0</strong></div></div>

    <button aria-label="Increase the counter by one" class="svelte-ltn89m"><svg aria-hidden="true" viewBox="0 0 1 1" class="svelte-ltn89m"><path d="M0,0.5 L1,0.5 M0.5,0 L0.5,1" class="svelte-ltn89m"></path></svg></button>
</div>
</section></main>

<footer class="svelte-1izrdc8"><p>visit <a href="https://kit.svelte.dev" class="svelte-1izrdc8">kit.svelte.dev</a> to learn SvelteKit</p>
</footer>



            
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I build SvelteKit with the node adapter, with the traditional JavaScript rollupjs output in the client code, e.g. without the `import` keyword?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my question is a [feature request](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/12) for SvelteKit.

This will be done after releasing version 1.0 of SvelteKit.

Credit for [dummdidumm](https://github.com/dummdidumm) for pointing me out for this while I [opened a duplicated issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/2458).